# Start by - and and by whitespace

Tags: regular-expressions

I want to select (by regexp) only text that start by **-** and end by **whitespace**

here text:

```
test-hello how-are again ok
maybe good but-some not good but-what about this
```

I use this regexp:

```
-.*\s-
```

but result is not correct:

[image]

The correct result is:

```
"-x "
"-f "
"-hello "
"-are "
"-some "
"-what "
```

How I can do this by regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.*` matches anything, and by default it is greedy. In your case,
you probably want a non-greedy search: `-.*?\s-`.

Answer (score 2):

```
‘*?’, ‘+?’, ‘??’
     These are “non-greedy” variants of the operators ‘*’, ‘+’ and ‘?’.
     Where those operators match the largest possible substring
     (consistent with matching the entire containing expression), the
     non-greedy variants match the smallest possible substring
     (consistent with matching the entire containing expression).

     For example, the regular expression ‘c[ad]*a’ when applied to the
     string ‘cdaaada’ matches the whole string; but the regular
     expression ‘c[ad]*?a’, applied to that same string, matches just
     ‘cda’.  (The smallest possible match here for ‘[ad]*?’ that permits
     the whole expression to match is ‘d’.)
```

-- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Regexp Special`

Hence:

```
-.*?\s-
```